# AWS CLI - [SSL : CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

Am trying to use AWS-CLI to retrieve aws elasticbeanstalk details, but am getting the following error.

**Error message:**

```
C:\abdul>aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-name myenvname

SSL validation failed for https://elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ [SSL
: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate
in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1056)
```

**Note:**

I can work without any issues when I try to retrieve my EC2 details,

```
C:\abdul>aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Above command works **without any issues**, I get the above error only when I try "elasticbeanstalk" commands.

**Note:**
I have all the necessary certificates required in place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found my way to this post while Googling.  In my case, the error message I received was:
`SSL validation failed for https://ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1091)`

I found [this blog](https://www.shellhacks.com/aws-cli-ssl-validation-failed-solved/) which told me to add an Environment Variable called `AWS_CA_BUNDLE` whose value was a path pointing to the CA Cert file (which I had saved on my local machine after requesting it from our corporate network team).  Once I added that environment variable, I was able to run my AWS CLI commands successfully!

Answer (score 6):

Steps to get this working in macOS/Linux

1. Download the Corporate Self-Signed Certificates using OpenSSL

   ```
      openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -servername ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com -connect ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 < /dev/null | awk '/BEGIN/,/END/{ if(/BEGIN/){a++}; out="cert"a".crt"; print >out}' && for cert in *.crt; do newname=$(openssl x509 -noout -subject -in $cert | sed -n 's/^.*CN=\(.*\)$/\1/; s/[ ,.*]/_/g; s/__/_/g; s/^_//g;p').pem; mv $cert $newname; done
   ```
2. Create a **bundle.pem** by concatenating all the files fetched from the first command.

> cat ec2_us-west-2_amazonaws_com.pem company_intermediate.pem company_root.pem >bundle.pem

3. Make it available in **AWS_CA_BUNDLE** environment variable.

> export AWS_CA_BUNDLE=/Users/velayutham/work/corp-cert/bundle.pem

4. aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 ==> This should work fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. This is how I resolved it.
Run below command first

```
$export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/company/certificate.crt
```

And then run AWS cli command

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --environment-name myenvname
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissons on the /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/botocore/cacert.pem file.  Mine was 640.  In fact, I had to adjust the permission on the whole install.